# null = "" for a string

Tags: java

In Java are these 2 statements the same?

```
String a = null;
String b = "";
```

It feels a bit of a dumb question but have a complete mental block currently.

Comment: This is a good question because the answer varies from language to language.

Comment: You can easily check: `if (a==b) System.out.println("same"); else System.out.println("not same");`

Comment: Dolph: Aside from Oracle, in what languages are null and the empty string the same?

Comment: @Gabe, Sybase treats null and an empty string as null. IBM DB2/UDB treats them as distinct values. Not certain if MS SQL does. I personally know of no programming language outside of various SQL implementations that do treat them as the same.

Comment: Nathan: MS SQL (before v7) treats the empty string as a single space. I'm pretty sure that's how Sybase works too.

Comment: @MAK: `==` wouldn't work even if the strings contents were identical.

Comment: @Anax it might if the language caches strings. Java caches small Integer objects for instance.

Comment: @Anax: For arbitrary Strings yes, but for this case case `==` works. `.equals` would throw an exception, and because of that it might not be as clear to the OP.

Comment: @anax this works in java, as long as ur not using `new String("foo")`
@dolph this would be a good question if it were not only tagged with java, because in java its just too easy to find out by your self. Asking for which languages treat ""/null in which way (and why) would be a good question.

Comment: @Graphain, MAK, fielding: thank you all for your insightful comments.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The empty string and `null` are different. The empty string is a string with no characters, `null` is not having a string at all.

You can call methods on an empty string but if you try to call a method on null you will get an exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String a = null;
    String b = "";
    System.out.println(b.length());
    System.out.println(a.length());
}
```

Output:

```
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Program.main(Program.java:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, an empty string is not null.

Answer (score 2):

They are most definitely not the same. Your String variable acts as a reference to an object in memory, and if it's set to null, it's not pointing to anything. If it's set to the empty-string value, it's pointing to that.

In my own coding, I generally set a String to "" instead of to null unless I have a special need for null. There are some libraries like Apache Commons that include helper classes like StringUtils that will collapse a check for null, the empty string, and even just whitespace into one call: StringUtils.isBlank(), StringUtils.isNotBlank(), etc. Pretty handy. Or you can write your own helper methods to do similar pretty easily.

Good luck as you progress in Java!

Comment: Or just call String's own isEmpty(), no need to mess with StringUtils isBlank().

Comment: That method has only been available since Java 6 and, unlike the StringUtils methods, is not null safe.

Answer (score 1):

The third possibility is:

```
String c;
```

All three are different, of course.

Comment: @Graphain: If they are instance members they are the same, but if they are statements in a method body then they are not the same. In the latter case attempting to read the variable c before it is initialized will give a compile error.

Comment: My comment went missing somehow. They are the same, it's just c will give an error (depending on your compile settings i believe) because you haven't explicitly told the compiler "i want null here" so it thinks you've forgotten. However, they are exactly equivalent, i.e. c==a.

Comment: Nope, an uninitialized local variable is not assigned any value by default. The compiler will warn you if you try to use its value before it's been assigned one.

Answer (score 0):

this is not as dumb as it sounds. it bothers even seasoned programmers. in many real world projects people often write something like `if(s==null || s.isEmpty())`, i.e. people treat `null` and `""` as **semantically equivalent** .

Comment: there are many lines like (str != null && "".equals(str.trim())) in the jdk and c# even has a String.IsNullOrEmpty() method. Still feels wrong.

Comment: As strings are immutable in c# it seems odd to me that all strings of the same value aren't the same string (thus making == okay for strings). However, it is important that ==null *isn't* true because otherwise how do we distinguish between non-provided values and provided-but-empty values.

Answer (score 0):

`null` means it refers to nothing, while empty string is a special string with zero length.

Answer (score 0):

String a = null;
String b = "";

The first statement in java initialises a variable handle.
there is no memory allocated for data to be saved.

The second statement shows two objects the first object being the handle (b) and second object being "" (if we ignore the higher concepts of string pooling in java where string is mutable and jvm gives out pooled instances of string)

thus the two lines are not same.

Answer (score 0):

No, They are different.
If you use a null String in a method, then Exception occur
But not occur in a empty String!